# How to load images dynamically from a folder rather than entering each image name in an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm putting each image from a folder into an array manually. Is there a way to do this dynamically but just using a for loop to iterate through the images in the folder?

index.html

```
<div class = "TestRotator">
<img src = "/Users/loh/Documents/ElectronJS/newapp1/newapp1/pages/images/Fib.png", height="300" id="rotator">
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator'); // change to match image ID
    var imageDir = '/Users/loh/Documents/ElectronJS/newapp1/newapp1/pages/images/';
    var delayInSeconds = 5;
    // set number of seconds delay
    // list image names
    var images = ['Camel.png', 'Noose.png', 'Sphinx.png'];
    var num = 0;
    var changeImage = function () {
        var len = images.length;
        rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
        if (num == len) {
            num = 0;
        }
    };
    setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you finding different solution if your code works ?

Comment: @GermanOchea His current approach requires tight coupling between the source code and the image filenames, which is a bit messy and harder to manage than would be ideal. It makes good sense to find an alternative if possible, I think

Comment: browsers can't do a list of file of a directory, you may use node JS

Comment: @CertainPerformance is right. It is a bit hard for me to manage since I have over 50+ images in the folder.

Comment: @MisterJojo 
Thanks! I haven't started using Node JS yet. Will start looking into it!

Comment: I just discovered that there is still a possibility to do this with a browser: use webkitdirectory, be careful, this is not standard. see here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to rename the images, eg from `Camel.png` and `Noose.png` to `0.png` and `1.png`. Then you could do:

```
let currentIndex = 0;
const totalImages = 3;
const changeImage = function () {
    num = (num + 1) % totalImages;
    rotator.src = imageDir + num + '.png';
};
```

Another option, if you can host the images on a *server* (either on localhost or on the internet somewhere), you could add a route on the server allowing the client JS to request a list of all files in the images directly, then iterate through it. Something that will let you do something like:

```
fetch('get-image-file-names')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((images) => {
    const rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');
    // etc; now use the `images` variable, which is an array of image names
    // sent to the client by the server
  });
```

Comment: or `num = ++num % totalImages`

Comment: That's possible, but I prefer to avoid using pre-increment or post-increment as an expression, it makes the code slightly harder to read at a glance IMO

Comment: it's just a matter of habit, the pre-increment deserves to be used more :)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks! The first solution worked out better for me. I have a broken image that shows up in my loop after it has finished looping through the set of images. I entered the right total  number of images as well. Any idea why this is happening? I tried removing the src in the img tag.

Comment: @ikol Are you sure you're starting the images at 0, as in my answer? `0.png` then `1.png` etc You could start at 1 instead, but that doesn't work all that well with the required modulo logic and would make things slightly more ugly

Comment: @CertainPerformance ah! I started from 1 instead of 0. Works now. Thanks!